# Did Bill Clinton still have his Presidential powers after his impeachment by the House of Representatives?

Tags: united-states, president, impeachment

United States President [Bill Clinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton) was impeached in 1998 for perjury and obstruction of justice by the House of Representatives.  He was not acquitted by the Senate until 1999.

> In 1998, Clinton was impeached by the House of Representatives for
>   perjury and obstruction of justice, relating to a sex scandal
>   involving White House employee Monica Lewinsky. Clinton was acquitted
>   by the Senate in 1999 and proceeded to complete his term in office.

**Did Bill Clinton still continue his Presidential duties while awaiting the Senate to vote?**

Comment: Have you reviewed the multitude of questions on impeachment on the SE too see if any address your question?

Comment: @DrunkCynic Yes.  I read through the impeachment tag questions.  I could have missed it, but I didn't see anything about what I am asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The constitution reads:

> The President, Vice President, and all civil Officers of the United States shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other High Crimes and Misdemeanors.

The President is not removed, suspended or loses any powers of the Presidency unless impeached *and* convicted.

Bill Clinton continued to exercise the powers of the presidency between his impeachment and his acquittal. For example, between his impeachment and acquittal there was a [major snowstorm in Illinois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_blizzard_of_1999). 45 counties in Illinois and some areas of Indiana were declared federal disaster areas by  Bill Clinton and eligible to receive federal aid. This declaration was an official act by the president, exercising powers granted to him as the head of the executive.